# RFSniffer only responds to some KAKU devices

Tags: raspbian

I have connected a 433Mhz sender and receiver to my RPi. I use https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils to send (codesend) and receive (RFSniffer) data.

I know they are both working, because RFSniffer responds on both the codesend command and the KAKU remote (PA3-1000R). However, RFSniffer doesn't respond to my wall switch (AWMT-003).

I know the wall switch is working, because the wall socket responds when I'm around 4 meter away. RFSniffer doesn't even respond when I place my wall switch very close to it.

What could be going on?

Btw: i also tried pilight, that doesn't respond to the remote or the wall switch

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps radio noise or system business.

Try my implementation at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D

It should use a lot less CPU.

It requires [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html) which may already be installed if you are using a recent Raspbian.